# Set text position and size based on dpi set on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Hi people of awesome minds,

I'm working on a tool for designing business cards. I've increased the dpi of my canvas to 200 so customers can design without having to work on the actual size.

```
canvas.width = 3.5 inches * 200;  // width would be 700px 
canvas.height = 2 inches * 200; // height would be 400px
```

My Question is how can I set the text to work with 200 dpi? What I did is this.

```
var scale_ratio = 200/72;
var pointsize = 14;
var xcord = 20;
var ycord = 20;

this.context.font = pointsize * scale_ratio + 'px' + " Arial";
this.context.fillText("Hello World", xcord, ycord + pointsize * scale_ratio);
```

Is what I did the correct way of doing it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ctx.setTransform

Rather the scale the font and all the render call arguments, set the transform so that all rendering is scaled for you.

Set up fonts, line widths, etc for the standard DPI (looks like you are using 72 DPI)

```
const nativeDPI = 72; // what ever value you where using
ctx.font = "14px Arial";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
const textPos = {x : 20, y : 20};
const box = {x : 3, y : 3, w : 246, h: 138};
```

When rendering scale to the correct DPI using the function `ctx.setTransform(xAxisX, xAxisY, yAxisY, yAxisY, originX, originY)` The first two values are the length and direction of a pixel's x axis, the next two are the y axis and the last two are the absolute canvas pixel coordinate of the origin.

```
const workingDPI = 200;
var scale = workingDPI / nativeDPI;  // get the scale change
ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, 0, 0);  // set the new scale

ctx.fillText("blah blah.", textPos.x, textPos.y);
ctx.strokeRect(box.x, box.y, box.w, box.h);
```

If you need to revert to the pixel scale you can set the default transform with

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Cool. I'll try this one out. I setTransform cross browser?